# Is it possible to suspend a docker container and save its state so that it can be resumed later?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gpu

This would be similar to putting a computer into a sleep mode. FYI: I'm asking this in the context of managing containers using Kubernetes.

The reason for asking is that we would like to run many interactive jobs and want to suspend these jobs when users are not actively working on them so that resources can be released and used by other users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `docker stop` and `docker start` commands. It would like you suspend pc.

All data produced inside container will be saved. But main process will receive `SIGTERM` signal. After docker start this process will be started again

Also take a look at `docker pause command`.

> The docker pause command suspends all processes in the specified
>   containers. On Linux, this uses the cgroups freezer. Traditionally,
>   when suspending a process the SIGSTOP signal is used, which is
>   observable by the process being suspended. With the cgroups freezer
>   the process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being
>   suspended, and subsequently resumed. On Windows, only Hyper-V
>   containers can be paused.

Comment: Wouldn't it restart the memory state as well? I want to save the memory state and reloads it when the container is resumed. That way, users don't have to rerun their work.

Comment: If you wanna to save memory data you can use `docker pause` command. I will update my answer.

Comment: stop/start are like turning off your pc. pause/unpause is like suspending - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/